# How to add dependency and use it via Grails web console plugin

Tags: grails, dependency-injection, grails-web-console

Depenedency wasn't added upfront in `BuildConfig.groovy`. I tried to add it and run it in runtime via web console:

```
import groovy.grape.Grape
Grape.grab(group : 'com.xlson.groovycsv', module : 'groovycsv', version : '0.2')
```

or

```
groovy.grape.Grape.initGrape()
@Grab(group='group : 'com.xlson.groovycsv', module : 'groovycsv', version : '0.2')
```

with no luck.

- Grails 2.5.4
- :console:1.5.11

Answer (score 0):

Everything works after using Grails classloader from `ctx.classLoader`:

```
import groovy.grape.Grape

ClassLoader classLoader = ctx.classLoader
def loadGrapes(classLoader){
    Map[] grapez = [[group : 'com.xlson.groovycsv', module : 'groovycsv', version : '0.2']]
    Grape.grab(classLoader: classLoader, grapez)
}
 
loadGrapes(classLoader)
//println (classLoader.loadClass('com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser'))

import com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser
```